# substiutiation value shown as plain text instead of value of href attribute

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an url value stored in a column *url* in mytable.
when the Interactive Report created, I use that column as LINK, in the target atribute URL chosen and its value setted into substiutation value *&url.* but the url shown as text plain inside  tag of the column. I want to be a value of an *href* attribute in  tag as it's default with any value in url target attribute but not column substitution.

when column substitution used: *&url.* it shown in the document as `<span>http://192.168.1.10/path/filename.png</span>`

when I use the url used directly, it shown in the document as `<a href="http://192.168.1.10/path/filename.png"></a>`

how to show the url substitiution as value of href attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state "Interactive Report" but you use the &COLUMN_NAME. syntax. That syntax is for Interactive Grid, not Interactive Report. In an interactive report the syntax is #COLUMN_NAME#
I did a test in an interactive report using the #URL# syntax with a column of type "Link" and the html generated contained the `href="`. Alternatively I used a column of type "Plain Text" with a column expression with value #LINK_NAME# - that generated identical markup as the other column.

Comment: Good points. It's worked using #URL# syntax.